# Cite only by DOI in rebuttal

Tags: peer-review, conference, paper-submission

I have to write a rebuttal for a machine learning conference in which I included a lot of new references (to prove broad interest). The rebuttal has a page limit of one, and my reference list is too long for that. Is it ok to cite the paper by only using the DOI in the rebuttal, if I cite the works in full in the actual submission in the final version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.  Contrary to Wolfgang's answer, the DOI is the easiest way for a reviewer to find your reference.  They can simply use the DOI resolver.  The advantage of DOIs is that they always find the document in one step.  Traditional citations do not necessarily do that.

Answer (score 3):

Make it easy for your reviewers to get what you are saying. Just a DOI is really hard for a reviewer because they have to walk to the computer, look up the DOI, and all that.

If you don't want to provide the full reference, just say "see Schneider et al., cited in the paper". That way, there is an easy place to go to to find the full title and reference.

Comment: The papers are new references though (mostly because they were published after I submitted my paper), so I can not do that, unfortunately.

Comment: Rebuttal systems are web-based systems, so when a reviewer consults the rebuttal, they have a web browser running and are only one copy-paste away from the referenced publication. See Anonymous Physicist's answer.

Comment: I don't understand -- why can't you cite these new papers? They may have been published after your paper was submitted, but since you're in the process of revision, I see no reason why you can't add new citations. Indeed, I would think that you *should*: After all, that would be useful for your readers!